# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ... in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have syntax error:

> (unexpected token "...") in line config.db.database;

This is code in file.

```
odas_web-0.2-alpha/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/rebuild.js:81
    depKeys.push(...Object.keys(rootPackageJson.dependencies || {}));

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
       at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zhaohe/down/odas_web-0.2-alpha/node_modules/electron-rebuild/lib/src/cli.js:17:19)
       at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the spread/rest syntax `...`, but the version of node you are running doesn't support it. Recommendation: upgrade to Node 10. If you use the newest version of the language, you don't have to play the game of "can I use this syntax?"

Comment: Umm. Supported since 6.x.x. The error is for a different reason

Comment: Dude you're trying to say you need a version of Node which is not even released for LTS yet. That's not true. This is supported many versions back. *" Upgrade to Node 10"* - That's your quote.